# how to add remove and show in widget when data is added to websocket?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, pusher, laravel-echo

i use `laravel_echo` and `flutter_pusher_client` packages for custom websocket. i can successfully fetch data in real time when backend sends. My data is number and message. and i send that coming number data as message to that number using `sms_maintained` package. My problem is how to show alltime data(past,present,future) that is coming when backend sends. It can be in anytime. should i use `StreamBuilder` or `Animated list`??. and little example would be appreciated. Here is websocket part code:

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_pusher_client/flutter_pusher.dart';
import 'package:laravel_echo/laravel_echo.dart';
import 'package:pursat_otp/provider.dart';
import 'package:sms_maintained/sms.dart';

import 'model/data_model.dart';
import 'model/pusher_model.dart';

class PusherSide extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PusherSideState createState() => _PusherSideState();
}

class _PusherSideState extends State<PusherSide> {
  FlutterPusher pusherClient;
  Echo echo;
  dynamic channel;
  Data data;

  // fetch declarations
  @override
  void initState() {
    fetchConf();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> fetchConf() async {
    try {
      var response = await Provider.dio.get('/conf/pusher');
      Conf conf = Conf.fromJson(response.data['conf']);
      debugPrint('${conf.pusherAppKey}');
      //websocket part
      FlutterPusher getPusherClient() {
        PusherOptions options = PusherOptions(
            host: conf.host,
            port: conf.port,
            cluster: conf.pusherAppCluster,
            encrypted: conf.encrypted);
        return FlutterPusher(conf.pusherAppKey, options, lazyConnect: false);
      }

      pusherClient = getPusherClient();

      echo = new Echo({
        'broadcaster': 'pusher',
        'client': pusherClient,
      });

      channel = echo.channel(conf.channel);
      channel.listen(conf.event, (e) {
        setState(() {
          data = Data.fromJson(e);
          debugPrint('$e');
        });
      });
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      debugPrint('${e.message}');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // how to show that e data here using StreamBuilder or AnimatedList or any Widget. e data comes as json at anytime during a day
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

anyway i solved above problem using `AnimatedList` widget. Let me know if who needs source code.